# Formatting long multiple for-in loops in Coffeescript

Tags: for-loop, coffeescript, formatting

Is there a way how to format multiple inner for-in loops to be written on more lines?

Example:

```
numbers = [1..20]
addLetters=  (number) ->
    pairs = []
    pairs.push number+"A"
    pairs.push number+"B"
    pairs

console.log pair for pair in addLetters number for number in numbers
```

Desired format, something like:

```
# NOT WORKING
console.log pair 
    for pair in addLetters number 
        for number in numbers
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PrimaMateria/had6f51v/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "NOT WORKING" loop is inside out. The outer loop goes first:

```
for number in numbers  
    for pair in addLetters number 
        console.log pair
```

Also, your `addLetters` function is overly complicated. You can build the return array with a single array literal:

```
addLetters = (number) ->
    [ "#{number}A", "#{number}B" ]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/b9p1v87m/